# TCP threaded server/client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm trying to make a threaded TCP server that accept multiple client. It's only accepting one client. Any idea on how to make the server accepting multiple client?

Here is what I tried so far:

I changed the server code. I ran both the server and the client, but it seems that it's only one thread is working. Should I change the ports or something?

Server code:

```
package tcpecho;

import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*;


class TCPserver  implements Runnable {
private static String clientMSG;
private static String serverRespond;
private static ServerSocket MySocket=null;
private static Socket client;
private static Socket connectionSocket = null;
private BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
public TCPserver(Socket client){
    TCPserver.client=client;}

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    try {
        MySocket  = new ServerSocket(6880);
        System.out.println("TCP server is listining");
    } catch (IOException e) {

    System.err.println("TCP server is not listining :   "+MySocket.getLocalPort());
    } 

    try {
        connectionSocket = MySocket.accept();
        (new Thread(new TCPserver(connectionSocket))).start();

        System.out.println("Is connected now : "+connectionSocket.getInetAddress());

    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.err.print("Accept failed");
    }
}



public void socketProcess( )
{

    try {
        inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Message from client is not reachable");
    }

    DataOutputStream outToClient = null;
    try {
        outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Message to client is not reachable");

    }

    try {
        clientMSG = inFromClient.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Message from client is not readable");
    }

    serverRespond = clientMSG +connectionSocket.getInetAddress()+ '\n';

    try {
        outToClient.writeBytes(serverRespond);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Message to client is not out");
    } 

    try {
        MySocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        System.err.println("Unable to close the socket");
    }

}



@Override
public void run() {
    socketProcess();

}
```

}

And here is my Client code:

```
package task3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;

class Client {
    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {

        String str;
        String strFromServer;
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        Socket client = null;
        // for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        int port = 6880;
        try {
            client = new Socket("192.168.56.1", port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't connect to the port" + port);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Write a message to the server :");
        str = inFromUser.readLine();

        outToServer.writeBytes(str + '\n');
        strFromServer = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("Respond from server: " + strFromServer);
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not deface your question once you've received answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after you do this

`connectionSocket = MySocket.accept();`

you need to pass this `connectionSocket` instance to a new Thread and call `start` on that Thread.

Also, move all the `connectionSocket` processing logic to your Thread class's `run` method
(this logic is currently in the `main` method after this line mentioned above).

For implementing your own `Thread`, you can either extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable`.

Check this link for some more details: [Java Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)

Comment: Also, you shouldn't create a new ServerSocket in the loop. Creating it once is enough.

Comment: Correct, he should remove the whole loop I guess. I guess he added it while trying to support accepting multiple clients.

Comment: I passed connectionSocket to a new thread, but I couldn't move all the process inside run method, it will throw a lot of errors.

Comment: connectionSocket = MySocket.accept();                                  (new Thread(new TCPserver(connectionSocket))).start();

Comment: You need to rework/redesign, I didn't mean you should just copy-paste it.

Comment: Looks good to me now. This is basically how I meant you should rework it. Looks good (though I did not run it).

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, If you are going to have multiple threads always opened to all your clients, you may want to check out the [java.nio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O#NIO_buffers) package which uses non blocking io.

This will allow you to handle many more connections.

Comment: The thread pool is abstracted out from the programmer's control. You usually use a nio.channel subclass and a selector. It is similar to the select() function in C/C++. Depending on how you are using your TCP server, it may be more advantageous to research java.nio.